# While True loop fails but While loop works, why?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration, boolean-logic

it's just simple squaring by repetitive addition. hope u guys might spare some time helping a brother out. totally missing something here because the while loop works:

```
x = 7
ans = 0
itersLeft = x
while (itersLeft != 0):
    ans = ans + x
    itersLeft = itersLeft - 1
print (str(x) + '*' + str(x) + ' = ' + str(ans))
```

but the "while True" loop fails:

```
x = 5
ans = 0
itersLeft = x
while True:
    if itersLeft != 0:
        ans = ans + x
        itersLeft = itersLeft - 1
print (str(x) + '*' + str(x) + ' = ' + str(ans))
```

Comment: What do you mean by “fails”? Also I recommend tagging the language you are using so that stackoverflow can style the colors of your code and so other users know what you’re working with here.

Comment: done deal. sorry. i thought i've tagged it already. must've missed it. anyways, by "fails" i meant, it didn't return anything on my interactive window whereas the former did.

Comment: Much better 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never break the loop when you use while True so it doesnt fail it just can not print anything put an else statement and a break inside the while true it should work just fine